# Mac: How to save alternate app icon in dock OSX xcode

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa

In xcode on OSX app, I can change the app icon in the dock by using this code:

```
let image = NSImage.init(named: NSImage.Name(rawValue: "AltAppIcon"))
NSApp.applicationIconImage = image
```

But when I close the application the dock image reverts back to the original icon. Is there a way I can save the alternate icon so it will show at all times even when the app is closed? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can implement a Dock tile plug-in. Much of the documentation for this has vanished, unfortunately. You can read about loadable bundles generally and plug-ins specifically in the [Code Loading Programming Topics](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/LoadingCode/LoadingCode.html).

You would create a new Bundle target in your app project. A Dock tile plug-in's bundle extension must be docktileplugin. You should add a class to that target that adopts and implements the [`NSDockTilePlugin`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsdocktileplugin) protocol. Set the `NSPrincipalClass` key in the bundle's Info.plist to the name of your class.

In the main app target, add the bundle target's product to be copied to the Contents/PlugIns directory in your app's bundle. Also, the app's Info.plist needs to have a key `NSDockTilePlugIn` whose value is the name of the plugin bundle.

When your plug-in is loaded, the system will call its `-setDockTile:` method, passing in an instance of [`NSDockTile`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsdocktile) for it to use. Your code can use that object to manipulate your app's Dock tile.