# Set menubar icon from ViewController

Tags: swift, xcode, appdelegate, menubar, nsstatusitem

How to change the menubar icon of a MacOS app from another ViewController?

- AppDelegate.swift (inits menubar icon)
- ViewController.swift (tries to set menubar icon ❌)

I found this but this isn't changing the menubar icon for me:
[Mac: How to save alternate app icon in dock OSX xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52469199/1762493)

```swift
let image = NSImage.init(named: NSImage.Name(rawValue: "AltAppIcon"))
NSApp.applicationIconImage = image
```

---

See how the BOINC icon has the little custom pause symbol/badge in the bottom right of it's menubar? This app's icon changes. Are they writing over the name of that file and changing it to the "paused icon" image maybe?

[image: BOINC menubar icon paused]

---

✅**UPDATE***

A `AppDelegate.swift` function that set the menubar icon worked:

`AppDelegate.swift`

```
func setIcon() {
  let onIcon = NSImage(named: "fv-mini-icon-green")
  statusItem.button?.image = onIcon
}
```

`ViewController.swift`

```swift
func taskOnIcon() {
  DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
    let appDele = NSApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    appDele.setIcon()
  })
}
```

Comment: The menu bar icon is part of an `NSStatusItem` instance

Comment: See here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsstatusitem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a way...

```
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {
    var statusBarItem: NSStatusItem!

    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {

        let statusBar = NSStatusBar.system
        statusBarItem = statusBar.statusItem(withLength: 16)

        let button = statusBarItem.button
        button?.image = NSImage(named: "fv-mini-icon-green")

    // .. other code here
```