# How to change a macOS menubar icon?

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui

I'm trying to change a macOS menubar icon at the click of a button based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61896055/set-menubar-icon-from-viewcontroller).

However, when I run the app and click the button, I get a `Could not cast value of type 'SwiftUI.AppDelegate' (0x20dfafd68) to 'MenuBarTest.AppDelegate' (0x10442c580).` error on this line:

```swift
let appDelegate = NSApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
```

**Main Swift File**

```swift
@main
struct MenuBarTestApp: App {
    @NSApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self) var delegate
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}

class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {
    var statusItem: NSStatusItem?
    var popOver = NSPopover()
    
    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ notification: Notification) {
        let menuView = MenuBarView()
        
        popOver.behavior = .transient
        popOver.animates = true
        popOver.contentViewController = NSViewController()
        popOver.contentViewController?.view = NSHostingView(rootView: menuView)
        
        statusItem = NSStatusBar.system.statusItem(withLength: NSStatusItem.variableLength)
        
        if let MenuButton = statusItem?.button {
            MenuButton.image = NSImage(named: "settings_bw")
            MenuButton.image?.size = NSSize(width: 18.0, height: 18.0)
            MenuButton.action = #selector(MenuButtonToggle)
        }
    }
    
    func setIcon(colorType:String) {
        var icon = NSImage(named: "settings_color")
        
        if colorType != "color" {
            icon = NSImage(named: "settings_bw")
        }
        
        statusItem?.button?.image = icon
    }
    
    @objc
    func MenuButtonToggle(sender: AnyObject) {
        if popOver.isShown {
            popOver.performClose(sender)
        } else {
            if let MenuButton = statusItem?.button {
                self.popOver.show(relativeTo: MenuButton.bounds, of: MenuButton, preferredEdge: NSRectEdge.minY)
                popOver.contentViewController?.view.window?.makeKey()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**MenuBar View**

```swift
struct MenuBarView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button(action: {
                let appDelegate = NSApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
                appDelegate.setIcon(colorType: "color")
            }, label: {
                Text("Change Icon")
            })
        }
        .frame(width: 150, height: 100)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I'll answer the question as asked, but then I'll follow up with why it actually doesn't matter because it's solving the wrong problem.

## Accessing the App Delegate in a SwiftUI lifecycle app

When you're using SwiftUI to manage your app lifecycle, you don't use an app delegate directly. SwiftUI will set the application's app delegate to an instance of its own class, `SwiftUI.AppDelegate`. This is what you saw when trying to cast it to `MenuBarTest.AppDelegate`. You can't cast it to your class, because it's not an instance of your class.

As a backwards compatibility feature, SwiftUI's app delegate lets you provide your own delegate instance to that it will forward to. This is wired up with the `NSApplicationDelegateAdaptor` property wrapper. If you want to access an instance, *that* `delegate` instance property is the way to get at it (*not* `NSApplication.shared.delegate`).

## Don't even use the App Delegate

You can disregard everything I said so far, because this is just a bad design, and you shouldn't use it. The App Delegate should be strictly limited to code related to managing the life cycle of your app and how it interacts with the system. It should *not* be a kitchen-junk-drawer of any code that fits.

Having random code right in the App Delegate is the AppKit equivalent to putting all your code in the `main()` function of a C program. It's done for brevity, but rarely a good idea. This is what you'll often see in tutorials, which aim to keep file and line count at a minimum, to illustrate some other point (e.g. Related to menu bar configuration, in this case).

As you'll notice, none of the code in this app delegate does much that's specific to the App life cycle. It just calls out to NSStatusBar. This code can just be put in any other appropriate place, like any other stateful SwiftUI code.

Comment: What do you recommend for changing the menubar icon outside of the App Delegate then?

Comment: @DarrellBrogdon Nothing, the code you're already using is fine, it's just misplaced. Look closely at `setIcon(colorType:)`. Is it a method override of a method from `NSApplicationDelegate`? Does it call any other methods unique to app delegate? Nope. Does it access any other properties that are unique the app delegate? Well yes (`statusItem`), but not really, because `statusItem` is just a reference to status item that was newly created by `NSStatusBar.system.statusItem(withLength: NSStatusItem.variableLength)`. All that's important here is that you call it once to create the status bar, ...

Comment: ... and then hold onto the result so you can update the icon later. So you can move the second half of your `applicationDidFinishLaunching` code (pertaining to initializing the `statusItem`) to be done in your [SwiftUI App's initializer](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-run-code-when-your-app-launches). Then you can move the `setIcon(colorType:)` function over as a whole. Though I'm not quite sure how to port over the `action`. In any case, start with the app-delegate based approach, but like with any other `main` function, break it apart after into tidy pieces.

Comment: Thanks for the help with the code organization but, unfortunately, this doesn't answer my question.

Comment: How’s that? The first half of my answer covers your question, at least as far as I understood it. The rest is just extra for doing it “better”. What part is left unanswered?

Comment: I guess the problem is that while reorganizing the code like you suggest makes sense and is very useful, your comment about not being sure how to port over the `action` appears to be significant.

Comment: I don't mean to distract you off course, let's merely get it working first, then focus on shuffling stuff around. Did you manage to get the icon to change with the plain app-delegate-based approach?

Comment: Unfortunately, no.

Comment: Wanna provide some details? Did the steps I outlined in my first half of the answer not work? What issues did you run into?

Comment: Apologies for the late reply.  I took some time off for the holidays.  The steps outline didn't work because I haven't been able to figure out how to port over the `action`. Without that, there is no way to display the popover and thus no way to change the icon.  Whether I move the code out of the app delegate or not is irrelevant when I can't change menubar icon by clicking a button in the menubar popover.

Comment: Here is the latest code: https://pastebin.com/HTVi8KVP -- it throws a `Cannot find 'statusItem' in scope` error on line 43 and so I guess my next problem is getting `statusItem` passed to `MenuButtonToggle()`

Comment: @DarrellBrogdon Let's continue this [in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250879/continued-from-https-stackoverflow-com-questions-74936104)